# C++ flush() not working? Can't use endl

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, flush

For a class assignment I have to overload the insertion and extraction operators. I'm having trouble getting it to print to the console.

**EDITED**

**Sorry, this is my first time posting. I realize that I didn't post enough info for you guys, I have updated with what should be the necessary code**

***driver.cpp***

```
#include "mystring.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char c[6] = {'H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O'}
    MyString m(c);
    cout << m;

    return 0;
}
```

***mystring.h***

```
class MyString
{
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const MyString&);

  public:
    MyString(const char*);
    ~MyString(const MyString&)

  private:
    char * str;  //pointer to dynamic array of characters
    int length;  //Size of the string

  };
```

***mystring.cpp***

```
#include "mystring.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

MyString::MyString(const char* passedIn){
    length = strlen(passedIn)-1;
    str = new char[length+1];
    strcpy(str, passedIn);
}

MyString::~MyString(){
  if(str != NULL){
    delete [] str;
  }
}

ostream& operator << (ostream& o, const MyString& m){
  for(int i = 0; i < strlen(m.str); i++){
    o << m.str[i];
  }
  o.flush();
  return o;
}
```

Comment: I suggest either posting the relevant `MyString` code, or making an [mcve] that doesn't require `MyString`.

Comment: Got a feeling it is because you are missing the null character

Comment: Furthermore, if `m.str` is a C-style string, this code will drop its last character. Multiple problems with the shown code.

Comment: I've updated my post to include more relevant/helpful info and to make what is hopefully a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

Comment: `strlen(passedIn)` this is undefined behavior as its not null terminated.

Answer (score 1):

use the `ostream::flush()` method. As in:

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& o, const MyString& m){
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(m.str)-1; i++){
        o << m.str[i];
    }
    o.flush();
    return o;
}
```

Comment: It would be beneficial to add to your answer for future readers how this is differs from using the manipulator [`std::flush`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush), as the OP is doing. If there is no such difference, perhaps this isn't the problem.

Comment: I've tried using flush as a member function too, same results. I've updated my post to try to include more helpful info.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to flush from inside an inserter. None of the standard inserters does that. Just add `std::cout << '\n';` after the call to your inserter in `main`.

The issue here is that `std::cout` is line buffered. That means it saves the inserted characters in an internal buffer until it sees a newline character (or until it's explicitly flushed). You'll see the same behavior if you insert a `std::string` object but don't end the line.